# Find $\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{i(ut+v\cos(t))}dt$ or $\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin(w+ut+v\cos(t))dt$ to invert $\frac{\sin(x)}x$

Tags: fourier-series, closed-form, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals, transcendental-equations

The solution to [$\operatorname{sinc}(x)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)$=a,0<a<\frac 2\pi$ involves inverting $ax-\sin(x)$ near $x=\frac\pi2 $ by transforming into $f_a(x)=a\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)-\sin \left(x+\frac\pi2\right)-\frac{\pi a}2+1=1+ax-\cos(x)$ with interval $L=f_a\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac{\pi a}2+1$. Define $h_a(f_a(x))=x$ on this interval with a [complex Fourier series](https://math24.net/complex-form-fourier-series.html)

$$h_a(x)=\frac{\pi^2 a+8}{16L}+\frac1{2L}\sum_{0\ne n\in\Bbb Z}e^\frac{\pi i n x}L\int_0^\frac\pi2te^{-\frac{\pi i n}Lf_a(t)}df_a(t)$$

integrating by parts:

$$h_a(x)=\frac{4\pi x+a\pi^2+8}{8(a\pi+2)}-\sum_{0\ne n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{ie^\frac{\pi i n (x-1)}L}{2\pi n}\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{-\frac{i\pi n}L(at-\cos(t)}dt=\frac{4\pi x+a\pi^2+8}{8(a\pi+2)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\pi n}\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin\left(\frac{\pi n (x-1)}L-\frac{\pi n}L(a t-\cos(t)\right)dt$$

Here is a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bx%2C%288%2B0.4Pi%5E2%2B4%CF%80+%281%2B0.4+x-cos%28x%29%29%29%2F%288+%282+%2B+0.4+%CF%80%29%29+-+sum%5Bsgn%28n%29%5E2+exp%28%28%CF%80+i+n+%28%281%2B0.4+x-cos%28x%29%29-1%29%29%2F%280.4%CF%80%2F2%2B1%29%29+i%2F%282%CF%80%28n%2B10%5E-5%29%29+Nintegrate%5B+exp%28-i+%CF%80+n%2F%280.4+%CF%80%2F2%2B1%29%280.4+t-cos%28t%29%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C%CF%80%2F2%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C-40%2C40%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%220.4+%CF%80%2F2%2B1%22) the complex Fourier series result that $f_a(h_a(x))=x$  and a [numerical test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sinc%28%CF%80%2F2%2B%288+%2B+0.4+Pi%5E2+%2B+4+Pi+%28%281-0.4+%CF%80%2F2%29%29%29%2F%288+%282+%2B+0.4+Pi%29%29+%2B+sum%5B+Nintegrate%5Bsin%28%28n+%CF%80+%28-1+%2B+%281-0.4+%CF%80%2F2%29%29%29%2F%281+%2B+%280.4+%CF%80%29%2F2%29+-+%28n+%CF%80+%280.4+t+-+cos%28t%29%29%29%2F%281+%2B+%280.4+%CF%80%29%2F2%29%29%2F%28n+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C%CF%80%2F2%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D%29) for the second series inverting $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ at a point. We find $\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}(x)=\frac\pi2+h_x\left(1-\frac{\pi x}2\right)$. However, no matter what is tried,

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{i(ut+v\cos(t))}dt\text{ or }\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin(w+ut+v\cos(t))dt\tag 1$$

seemingly cannot be evaluated using [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), [Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), [Anger Weber](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10), and [Lommel](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LommelFunction.html) functions or otherwise as a closed form. For example,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{i (u t-v\cos(t))}=\int_0^\frac\pi 2 \cos(ut)\cos(v\cos(t))-i\cos(ut)\sin(v\cos(t))+i\sin(ut)\cos(v\cos(t))+\sin(ut)\sin(v\cos(t))dt= \cos\left(\frac{\pi u}2\right) s_{0,u}(v)-u\sin\left(\frac{\pi u}2\right)s_{-1,u}(v)+\color{red}{\int_0^\frac\pi 2 \sin(u t)\sin(v\cos(t))dt}+i\color{red}{\int_0^\frac\pi 2\sin(ut)\cos(v\cos(t))dt}\end{align}$$

with Lommel $s_{a,b}(z)$ in [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mundher-Khaleel/post/Can_anybody_solve_the_integration/attachment/59d62aad79197b80779890e3/AS%3A340147343249408%401458108854707/download/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2%282%29.pdf) [3.715,3.716](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEwGg.jpg) and can simplify into Anger Weber or Bessel functions. Additionally, a [Jacobi Anger expansion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobi-AngerExpansion.html) uses the Bessel J function:

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{iv\cos(t)}e^{i ut}dt=-\sum_{m\in\Bbb Z}\frac{i^{m+1}}{m+u} J_m(v)\left(e^{\pi i \frac{m+u}2}-1\right)$$

but this is not a closed form for the Fourier series coefficients.

How can we evaluate $(1)$, the integrals in red, or the above series?

Comment: Hello Have you think about the Inverse laplace method see https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3110/5/2/43 ? Good luck in your investigation .

Comment: @ErikSatie That article is using the sinc function to approximate an inverse Laplace transform, but the question is about finding the [Fourier coefficient “transform”](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-fourier-coefficients/) of the sinc function. How would the article apply to the question?

Comment: Excellent question why not tackle the problem with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform instead of Fourier series ? see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361229/compare-fourier-and-laplace-transform .See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377042723001796